# os.rename can't see excel files that have errors with recursive cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, rename

I need to extract xlsx files from one folder and move it to another. There are no problems with copies but for some reason I can't rename part of the files (which I need to do because some of the files are named in a wrong way) because os.rename throws FileNotFoundErrors. As I've discovered, problematic files have excel warnings inside about recursive functions. At the same time, files without problems are easily renamed. I can't change original files.

```
# Define directories with data
base_dir = 'J:/.../data/'
storage_dir = 'R:/.../data_preparation/'

# Iterate over dt.datetime list
for d in dates_range:
   
   # Search for the folder with this date and copy file with specific name from it
   directory = base_dir + str(d.year) + '/' + dates[d.month] + '/' + str(d)[8:10] + '/'
   for f in os.listdir(directory):
      if ...:
         fin_path = directory + f
         shutil.copy2(fin_path, storage_dir + 'input/')

         # Rename file to one specific format due based on the date
         os.rename(storage_dir + 'input/' + f, storage_dir + 'input/{}'.format(str(d)[:10] + '.' + f.split('.', 1)[-1]
```

I've tried os.chmod because earlier there were several strange files from other set by this source that wouldn't open without setting 'stat.S_IWRITE' but in this case it broke the scene even more:
Even files without problems stopped opening
So, this idea was aborted.

What is more interesting, I can open these files via read_excel with the very link that os.rename can't find.

Sadly, due to the security reasons I can't share the problematic files.